# Any documentation for HERE Traffic Incidents API response?

Tags: here-api

The HERE Traffic API developers guide provides examples of responses to Traffic Incident Data requests but does not explain the response structure or describe the purpose/content of each returned element. Instead it states that

> The response structure is based on the TML Formal Specification. For more information on TML specification, contact Technical Customer Support.

I'm not familiar with TML (presumably Traffic Markup Language), nor can I find any reference to it online. Is the TML specification available?

Answer (score 2):

I've got an answer for you. Right now the information is *not* online so you do need to reach out. You should do so, and if you have any trouble, reach out to me directly. I'm also checking to see if we can get this information public. That may not happen quickly, but I'm going to dig more. But for now, please do as it stays and contact support.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get TML XSD using API which is documented on following page but you need access Key which you should be able to get it by creating freemium account

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/additional-parameters.html